# Matching and replacing newline character using Lua pattern patch

Tags: string, lua, latex

This is a follow up to a question I asked in the [LaTeX community](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/641271/how-to-make-it-so-that-newcommand-takes-the-rest-of-my-line-as-argument) regarding how to format items in the `itemize` environment. It turns out I got a response to that question using `lua`, but now I want to extend the `lua` code so I have a more `lua` programming centered question.

The answer proposes using `string.gsub` to replace pattern-matched parts of the string to something else. For example, the below code:

`s = string.gsub ( s , '\\sitem%s+(.+)' , '\\item\\makefirstuc{%1},' )`

will replace `\item hello world` to `\item\makefirstuc{hello world}`.

Here's the problem though, sometimes I have new lines in the string after item, for instance:

```
\item hello
world
```

I would like to replace that with:

```
\item\makefirstuc hello world
```

Does anyone know how I can do that?

## Edit

I just tried the solution proposed by Wiktor but it wouldn't work for the case:

```
\item hello
world
\end{itemize}
```

Here's a full script to demonstrate:

```
-- test.lua
s = "\\sitem  Hello\n\\end{itemize}"

print(s)

result = string.gsub ( s, '\\item%s+(.+)' , function(x) return 
    '\\item\\makefirstuc{' .. string.gsub(x, '\n', ' ') .. '},' 
end )
print("\nAfter gsub")
print(result)
```

The above script outputs

```
\sitem  Hello
\end{itemize}

After gsub
\sitem  Hello
\end{itemize}
```

But I want it to output:

```
\sitem  Hello
\end{itemize}

After gsub
\item\makefirstuc {Hello},
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the logic here?

Comment: characters and/or space starting from after the `\sitem` command all the way to the next control sequence starting with a backslash `\` symbol and not including the backslash.

Comment: Like `result = string.gsub ( s, '\\sitem%s+(.-)(\n\\)' , '\\item\\makefirstuc {%1},%2')`? See https://ideone.com/uTM7ci

Comment: Yes. Could  you add that to your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function as a replacement argument:

```lua
result = string.gsub ( s, '\\sitem%s+(.-)(\n\\)' , '\\item\\makefirstuc {%1},%2')
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/uTM7ci).

*Details*:

- `\\sitem` - a `\sitem` fixed string
- `%s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.-)` - Group 1 (`%1`): any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(\n\\)` - Group 2 (`%2`): a newline and a `\`.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work for strings like `s = "\\sitem  Hello\n\\end{itemize}"`

Comment: @user32882 Sure, just add `s` where it was: `string.gsub ( s, '\\sitem%s+(.+)' ,`

Comment: Please see edit to original question

Comment: @user32882 I updated the solution.

Answer (score 2):

No need for complicate lua constructs, you can simply use the `getitems` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{getitems}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}

% borrowed from biblatex
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\unspace}{%
  \ifbool{hmode}
    {\ifdimgreater\lastskip\z@
       {\unskip\unspace}
       {\ifnumgreater\lastpenalty\z@
          {\unpenalty\unspace}
          {}}}
    {}}  
\makeatother

\def\doitem#1{\item \makefirstuc{#1}\unspace\ifnum\thecurrentitemnumber=\thenumgathereditems.\else,\fi}%

\let\origitemize\itemize
\let\origenditemize\enditemize

\usepackage{environ}

\RenewEnviron{itemize}{%
  \expandafter\gatheritems\expandafter{\BODY}%
  \gathereditem{0}%
  \origitemize%
   \loopthroughitemswithcommand{\doitem}%
  \origenditemize%
}  

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't want the `.` pattern match to be greedy, so this uses the frontier pattern to stop at the next backslash or at the end of the string. This will also mean that it can match multiple items, since the backslash isn't contained in the match. (see [Lua Manual § 6.4.1 - Patterns](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1))

> `%f[set]`, a *frontier pattern*; such item matches an empty string at any position such that the next character belongs to *set* and the previous character does not belong to *set*. The set *set* is interpreted as previously described. The beginning and the end of the subject are handled as if they were the character '`\0`'.

```lua
s = s:gsub(
    "\\sitem%s+(.-)\n?%f[\\\0]",
    function(it)
        return "\\item\\makefirstuc{" .. it:gsub("\n", " ") .. "},\n"
    end
)
```

Input:

```latex
\sitem Hello
World
\sitem Something else
\end{itemize}
```

Output:

```latex
\item\makefirstuc{Hello World},
\item\makefirstuc{Something else},
\end{itemize}
```